# Physical model for multilocation RCBD with repeated measures in time

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, experiment-design, crossed-random-effects

I am trying to write a model for an experimental design that looks like this:

There are 5 **farms (A,B,C,D,E)** , and each farm has a RCBD design with 2 **treatments(1,2)** randomized in 4 **blocks** in each farm. Repeated measurements of **response** are taken from each treatment at **4 dates**.

I want to test the fixed effects of **treatment** and **time** with their interactions. I have trouble specifying the random effects for this model.

```r
m1 <- lmer(response ~ treatment * time + (1 | farm) + 
             (1|farm: block) + (1 | farm :block: treatment))
```

For a separate model if I decide **farms**, **treatment**, **time** and their interactions as fixed effects, I write the following:

```r
m2 <- lmer(response ~ farms * treatment * time + (1|farm: block) + 
              (1 | farm :block: treatment))
```

The question is how do I factor the correlated errors for time into these models?

Comment: What is the purpose of the repeated measurements ? Are you interested in the change over time, or something else ? What is the time between measurements ?

Comment: @RobertLong, yes, the change over time. The time between each measurements are roughly 1 month apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far more of a comment, but too ong for comment box:  For your first model, the last model term

```r
(1 | farm :block: treatment)
```

seems in reality an error term (block/treatment interactions is usually seen as error) so could be omitted from the model.

For the second model, the fixed effects `farms * treatment * time`  will eat all of the degrees of freedom, so leaving nothing for the random effects or error variance. That model is overparametrized. It also looks strange to include `farm`  as a fixed effect, in such designs mostly `farm` is seen as a sample of a larger population of farms to which you want to  generalize the conclusions, as such it is used as a random effect.

To say more about how to model time correlations, you need to tell us if you treat `time` as numerical or simply as a factor.